# Get the count of observations in a specific column in R

Tags: r

Below is a sample Data Frame

```
var_1 <- c(2,5,6,7,9)
var_2 <- c(1,"NA",3,6,1)
var_3 <- c(9,4,6,"NA","NA")
varDF <- data.frame(var_1,var_2, var_3)
```

How do I get the count of observations in a particular column? e.g  column `var_1` I'd like the output to be 5 & and `var_2` to be 4 (Because it has skipped the NA)

Comment: `sum(!is.na(x))`

Comment: `apply(varDF, 2, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))`. Be carefull between `NA` and `'NA'`

Answer (score 0):

Using `colSums` and `!is.na()`:

```
colSums(!is.na(varDF))

var_1 var_2 var_3 
    5     4     3
```

Or if your `NAs` are actually `"NA"`, use the following, although I advise to use `NAs` in `numeric` and `integer` columns:

```
colSums(varDF != "NA")
```